# Why is System.ComponentModel.AttributeCollection indexer inconsistent?

Tags: c#, reflection

In reference to System.ComponentModel.AttributeCollection.this[Type t] indexer, the docs at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yadycs8s.aspx say the following

> If the attribute does not exist in the collection, this property returns the default value for the attribute type.

With that in mind the following code works as expected: (> represents output)

```
using System.ComponentModel;
var attrCollection = new AttributeCollection();
Console.WriteLine(attrCollection[typeof(BrowsableAttribute)] != null);
> "True"
```

prints "True" as I would expect. However trying with another random attribute like DebuggerDisplay, the indexer returns null:

```
var attrCollection = new AttributeCollection();
Console.WriteLine(attrCollection[typeof(System.Diagnostics.DebuggerDisplayAttribute)] != null);
> "False"
```

Any ideas on what is different between these attributes, causing the different behavior? It is unclear to me what msdn means by 'default value for the attribute type' as it is not simply null. I thought perhaps the problem was an attribute type with no parameterless constructor, but BrowsableAttribute requires one argument, as does DebuggerDisplayAttribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is explicitly documented in the MSDN library article for AttributeCollection:

> While most attributes have default values, default values are not required. If an attribute has no default value, null is returned from the indexed property that takes a type. When defining your own attributes, you can declare a default value by either providing a constructor that takes no arguments, or defining a public static field of your attribute type named "Default".

BrowsableAttribute has such a default value, provided by its Default field, so your test succeeds.  It makes class members browsable by default when the attribute is missing.

DebuggerDisplayAttribute has neither a default constructor nor a Default field.  Which makes sense if you think about it, there is no meaningful default that would be useful in the debugger.

Comment: whoa, I see, right in front of my eyes on the main page! thanks